# Build gradle is crashing when I put the command :compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')

Tags: sqlite, react-native

Build is failing once the gradle file is updated (`compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')` is added to the dependencies in **/app/build.gradle** )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsXxq.jpg.
When I comment compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage') no erro appears

Comment: What does your MainActivity look like?

Comment: package com.vxm_noticias;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "VXM_NOTICIAS";
    }
}